# How to Retrieve the latest no. 3rd record from database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, relational-database

I am not getting that how to retrieve the latest no 3rd record from database. Suggest relevant query for it.

```
$sql = " select top 3 from chat ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo  $row['message'];
}
} else {
 echo "0 results";
 }
```

here is my database

```
 user_id        message                    sent_on
   2        Ask relevent question      2017-06-20 20:04:56
   2        i don,t know               2017-06-20 20:04:48
   1         having cup of tea         2017-06-20 20:04:46
   2         thank you                 2017-06-20 20:04:39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the nth record from the databse use this mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT n-1,1
```

To get the top three records from your table, which is recently inserted

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY sent_on LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: i want to retrieve 3rd no record which i recently inserted.here in my database i want "having cup of tea" as a result.suggest me query for it

Comment: Then use the first query, and replace n with 3, so your query becomes `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 2,1`

Comment: ya sure i am trying this.if it works for me then i will accept this.